# select all check box not checked when click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

i want to check all checkboxes when selectall checkbox is ticked ,but in my case the checkboxes are made dynamically .when i click on the selectall checkbox all the checkboxes are checked but not the selectall checkbox,its unchecked.
**javascript**

```
 function selectAll() {
        alert("enter selectall");
        $('.checkall').prop('checked', isChecked('selectall'));
    }

    function isChecked(checkboxId) {
        alert(checkboxId);
        alert("enterischecked");
        var id = '#' + checkboxId;
        return $(id).is(":checked");
    }


    function resetSelectAll() {
        alert("resetselectall");
        // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
        // and viceversa
        if ($(".checkall").length == $(".checkall:checked").length) {
            $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
        }
    }
```

**HTML CODE**

```
 <body>
<table id="notificationsTableId" style="width: 1744px;">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 30px;" aria-label="">
                <input type="checkbox" id="selectall" onclick="selectAll();">Select all</input>
            </th>
            <th tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 203px;">Type</th>
            <th tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 354px;">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody role="alert">
        <tr class="results-table-row odd">
            <td align="center">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkall" name="selectedId" value="" onclick="resetSelectAll();" />
            </td>
            <td>Stop Noted Record</td>
            <td>Closed (No investigation required)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="results-table-row even">
            <td align="center">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkall" name="selectedId" value="" onclick="resetSelectAll();" />
            </td>
            <td>Stop Noted Record</td>
            <td>Open (New)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="results-table-row even odd">
            <td align="center" class=" ">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkall" name="selectedId" value="" onclick="resetSelectAll();" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**NOTE**

```
i am using ie8
```

Comment: you should provide the rendered HTML markup and maybe a jsfiddle

Comment: @A.Wolff i have change the html now

Answer (score -1):

when this is called by the onClick handler:

```
function selectAll() {
        alert("enter selectall");
        $('.checkall').prop('checked', isChecked('selectall'));
    }
```

the `selectall` checkbox currently is NOT checked. This function is resetting immedialtely, so the box will stay unchecked. The "checking" actually happens AFTER the onClick routine returns

this will do the Trick:

```
function selectAll() {
        alert("enter selectall");
        $('.checkall').prop('checked', !(isChecked('selectall')) );
    }
```